# How to get Image (not url or NSData )from server using Alamofire

Tags: iphone, swift, alamofire

I am trying to get image from server using Alamofire. It is working in postman ref:attachement

Below is my code for reference:

```
let headers = ["Authorization" : APITOKEN,"Content_Type" : CONTENT_TYPEVAL]


Alamofire.request(urlString!,  method: .get, parameters: nil, encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers:headers ).responseJSON { (response) in
switch response.result {
case .success(let origObject):
    debugPrint(origObject)

    if let object = origObject as? Dictionary<String,AnyObject>
    {


    }

    completion(.failure(Ya3ClientError.serverUnknownError))

case .failure(let e):
    debugPrint("error:\(e.localizedDescription)")


}
```

Getting error "JSON could not be serialized because of error:\nThe data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format."

Any help how to solve this issue.

Comment: You call `responseJSON` on your request, meaning that the response will be interpreted as JSON. Pointless since it's a binary file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `.responseJson`, you can try using `.responseData` to get a `Data` object and create the image using `UIImage(data:)`

Take a look at [this](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire#downloading-data-to-a-file)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `UIImage` from a `Data` object, which you get from the response with Alamofire. However, without seeing your JSON response I cannot help with the exact code. If the response only contains the image as its data, then you can use

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, "https://myUrl/myPicture.png").response { (request, response, data, error) in
    myImageView.image = UIImage(data: data)
}
```

You can also have a look at the [Alamofire Image](https://github.com/Alamofire/AlamofireImage) library.